# Is this an optimal xpath query?

Tags: bash, optimization, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xpath select multiple attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/xpath-select-multiple-attr)

I have xml that looks like:

```
<records>
 <record key='1' att1='a' att2='2'> 
 <record key='2' att1='b' att2='4'> 
</records>
```

And this xpath command:

```
xpath -s ' ' -q -e "//record[@key='1']/@att1|//record[@key='1']/@att2" /tmp/xmlfile.log
```

To get `att2` should I **again** search for `where @key=1`?

Once I have the `<record>` with `key=1`, I should be able to get any attributes I want without searching again. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: do not duplicate questions but improve your existing ones

Comment: Sorry , here is the answer for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/xpath-select-multiple-attr