# How to select two attributes from the same node with one expression in XPath?

Tags: xpath, attributes

For example:

```
//person[@id='abc123']/@haircolor|/@weight"
```

PS. there are lots of "person" records

Comment: I couldn't do better than `//person[@id='abc123']/@haircolor|//person[@id='abc123']/@weight`. It seems `//person[@id='abc123']/(@haircolor|@weight)` doesn't work because `|` has to be on the first level.

Comment: Do you want select all person elements based on attribute conditions, or you want select the value of the attributes?

Comment: @Kobi: your "better" will show you only `@haircolor`, and `@weight` in the case `@haircolor` does not exist.

Comment: @empo - is that the first one, `//person[@id='abc123']/@haircolor|//person[@id='abc123']/@weight` ? I've tested it here: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Comment: @Kobi: yes, it is. The one provided in your answer is correct.

Comment: @Kobi: +1, nice online tester :D

Comment: "It seems //person[@id='abc123']/(@haircolor|@weight) doesn't work because | has to be on the first level." - that's only true in XPath 1.0 There's nothing in the question that says this has to be XPath 1.0.

Comment: http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/quick_ref.html

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```
//person[@id='abc123']/@*[name()='weight' or name()='haircolor']
```

If you're using an XPath 2.0 processor, you may also use a prettier option:

```
//person[@id='abc123']/(@haircolor|@weight)`
```

Comment: `//person[@id='abc123']/(@haircolor|@weight)` is valid XPath - but you need an XPath 2.0 processor to run it.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks, good to know! Unfortunately, I usually deal with the older version. Anyway, I'll take your word for it and update the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kobi - is it also possible to concatinate the output? Because running my XPath expression based on your answer leads me to a double output.

Comment: @Vilius - It shouldn't duplicate anything, as far as I know. I'm not sure what you mean by "concatinate"... It is probably best is you ask a new question with the exact the details.

Answer (score 31):

Are you wanting to search for person nodes based on the value of multiple attributes.  If that's the question then you can just use ands e.g.

```
//person[@id='abc123' and @haircolor='blue' and @weight='...']
```

If you want to search on a single attribute, but return the values of the other attributes, I would do something like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="person[@id='abc123']">
     <xsl:value-of select="@haircolor"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="@weight"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the values of the specified attributes I would suggest introducing a variable for the requested person.

```
<xsl:variable name="person" select="//person[@id = 'abc123']" />
```

After that you can get any attribute from the requested person by using the specified variable.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$person/@haircolor" />
<xsl:value-of select="$person/@weight" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample XML:

```
<X>
<Y ATTRIB1=attrib1_value ATTRIB2=attrib2_value/>
</X>

string xPath="/" + X + "/" + Y +
"[@" + ATTRIB1 + "='" + attrib1_value + "']" +
"[@" + ATTRIB2 + "='" + attrib2_value + "']"
```

XPath Testbed:
http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm