# Google Sheets importXml

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to target a price on a website using an importXML from Google Sheets. The code I'm targeting looks like:

```
  <span class="new_price" id="final_price">£29.99</span>
```

Becuase its inside a class 'new_price' my import isnt working:

```
  =importXml("http://www.hardware-ironmongers.com/details.aspx?code=7751913"; "//span[@id='final_price']")
```

Any ideas how to target an ID inside a class?

Cheers

Comment: Edited your tags so the XML experts can edit what I think is called the 'xpath' in your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select two attributes from the same node with one expression in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/how-to-select-two-attributes-from-the-same-node-with-one-expression-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert, but this looks like it may put you on the right path:

[How to select two attributes from the same node with one expression in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/xpath-select-multiple-attr)

Comment: Thanks, then answer was in a comment at the base of that post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6029286/925594. Basically I needed an 'and' statement. The final code looks like: =importXml("http://www.myurl"; "//span[@class='new_price' and @id='final_price']")