# Behat/Mink is it possible to do a find through an incomplete string?

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

I've been working in BDD through Behat|Mink.

However I'm failing in finding an input (field) with an ID or Name if they aren't complete.

I intended to do something like:

```
  $field = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findField( "*first_name*" );
```

where the **'*'** meant that can be any piece of string there.

The problem is that i have a case where I can't know for sure the complete ID cause:

```
  id="<random-string>_<actual-field-name>_<random-number>"
```

Any idea how can I do this?

What have I  tried

```
- get it through label (for some reasons there are some labels that dont have 'for' attribute and sometimes the name is a sentence and not an simple name)
- get it through css/classes (to many variables)
```

Edit:

I've created a php function to read the attribute and return the value of the intended attribute.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string  $haystack The complete html
 * @param string  $needle   The string with the part of the attribute value
 * @param string  $tag      The tag of where the attribute should belong
 * @param string  $attr     The attribute to ifnd
 * @return string
 */
protected function findCompleteAttribute( $haystack, $needle, $tag = null, $attr = 'id' )
```

However, in cases that there is another fields (ex: hidden login form) and the needle is also in those inputs, it will get them if they're first.

So I need to specify the form, however, once more, there I haven't a way to find a form through name:

```
  $field = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find( 'named', array( 'form', $formName ) );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After studying more Xpath and based on my comment on @gontrollez answer it can be resolved by a single Xpath:

```
//form[ @name = 'Register' ]//input[ contains( @id, 'username' )]
```

This will return all input that have "username" on their id attribute and the input is inside any form that it's name attribute is equal to "Register"

```
<form>
    <input id="login_username" type="text"/>
</form>
<form name="Register>
    <div>
        <input id="other_username" type="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

this will return only the second input

Answer (score 2):

Try using XPath:

```
$el = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', "//input[contains(@id,'first_name')]");
```

Comment: This does all the work I've made by and on the function I did by hand (i wish i knew it before).
However I still have the problem of when there are 2 or more fields that contain 'first_name' so I've decided to add more details to the find and now I'm using that way

Comment: You can refine the XPath expression including more than 1 attribute condition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/xpath-select-multiple-attr

Comment: Thanks @gontrollez, but I don't think that multi attribute search will do, cause the problem is that I need a way to find a 'form' so that i can then search for the input inside.
something like: 



`$form = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find( 'xpath', "//form[conains(@name,'Register']");
$input = $form->find( 'xpath', //input[contains(@id,'first_name')]");`
but till now wasn't successful on searching for the form