# Get value to 2 attribute from a xpath node for anchor tag

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following extracted with the help of xpath:

```
In [206]: list = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="gs_top"]/div[@id="gs_bdy"]/div[@id="gs_ccl"]/div[@id="gsc_ccl"]/div[@class="gsc_1usr gs_scl"]/div[@class="gsc_1usr_text"]/h3[@class="gsc_1usr_name"]/a')

In [208]: for item in list:
    print(etree.tostring(item, pretty_print=True))
   .....:
<a href="/citations?user=lMkTx0EAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Jason Weston</a>
<a href="/citations?user=RhFhIIgAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Pierre Baldi</a>
<a href="/citations?user=9DXQi8gAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Yair Weiss</a>
<a href="/citations?user=J8YyZugAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Peter Belhumeur</a>
<a href="/citations?user=ORr4XJYAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Serge Belongie</a>
```

Now I can either extract the href by appending `/@href` or the text with the help of `text()`. But how can I get both of them in one go, as shown in an answer here: [How to select two attributes from the same node with one expression in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029232/how-to-select-two-attributes-from-the-same-node-with-one-expression-in-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.xpath("@href|text()")` on every element this way:

```
for item in list:
    href, text = item.xpath("@href|text()")
    print(href, text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <body>
...     <a href="/citations?user=lMkTx0EAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Jason Weston</a>
...     <a href="/citations?user=RhFhIIgAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Pierre Baldi</a>
...     <a href="/citations?user=9DXQi8gAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Yair Weiss</a>
...     <a href="/citations?user=J8YyZugAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Peter Belhumeur</a>
...     <a href="/citations?user=ORr4XJYAAAAJ&amp;hl=en&amp;oe=ASCII">Serge Belongie</a>
... </body>
... """
>>> 
>>> tree = fromstring(data)
>>> 
>>> for item in tree.xpath("//a"):
...     print(item.xpath("@href|text()"))
... 
['/citations?user=lMkTx0EAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII', 'Jason Weston']
['/citations?user=RhFhIIgAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII', 'Pierre Baldi']
['/citations?user=9DXQi8gAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII', 'Yair Weiss']
['/citations?user=J8YyZugAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII', 'Peter Belhumeur']
['/citations?user=ORr4XJYAAAAJ&hl=en&oe=ASCII', 'Serge Belongie']
```

Comment: Can I not encode it in xpath somehow. May be like this: `list = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="gs_top"]/div[@id="gs_bdy"]/div[@id="gs_ccl"]/div[@id="gsc_ccl"]/div[@class="gsc_1usr gs_scl"]/div[@class="gsc_1usr_text"]/h3[@class="gsc_1usr_name"]/a/(@href|text())')`. But this gives error but I hope you get what I am asking.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam I don't think you can do that in a single go. Using an inner xpath to get either href or text has the context of a specific node you are calling it on, but if you would try to incorporate it into the main expression, you'll lose the context. Note that you can also get the `href` from `item.attrib["href"]` and text from `item.text_content()`. Hope that helps.